# replace() does not replace the selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I want to remove `/view-photo/P1270649` from an URL that I have. I'm currently using this to do so:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var replaced = pathname.replace('/view-photo/' + /([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
```

However, nothing happens when I try to use this. You can [see it in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/nrNrP/). How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't combine a string and a regular expression in that way.  The simplest thing to do would be to place it entirely in the regex:

```
var replaced = pathname.replace(/\/view-photo\/([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
```

What happened originally was that the regular expression object was being converted into a string, which would actually made your `replace()` look something like this:

```
var replaced = pathname.replace("/view-photo//([A-Z0-9]+)/g", '');
```

...which would have searched for the literal version of that string, which of course is not there.

Answer (score 1):

The ' character is failing when building the regex expression:

```
 var replaced = pathname.replace('/view-photo/' + /([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
```

should be

```
var replaced = pathname.replace(/view-photo/([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest another approach (pure js)

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var i  = pathname.slice(0,pathname.indexOf('/view-photo'));
```

Comment: I'm getting an error if I use `indexOf` so I can't use that function

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = 'http://localhost/galleri/view-photo/P1270649';
    var replaced = pathname.replace(/view-photo\/([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
    // or you can use it like
    //var replaced = pathname.replace(/\/view\-photo\/([A-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
    alert(replaced);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrNrP/5/)